# How to add javascript function in c# by using htmlgeneric control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net c# . I want to add javascript function in c# by using htmlgeneric control .I have used code ,

```
HtmlGenericControl scriptTagLinks = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
scriptTagLinks.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript"; 
string scrip = "$(function () {$([src='" + url + "']" + ").pinit();});";
    // txtDesc.Text = rdr.GetString(4);
    // TxtLink.Text = rdr.GetString(6);
scriptTagLinks.Attributes["src"] = scrip;
this.Controls.Add(scriptTagLinks);
```

But i should get like this ,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {


        $("[src='/pinterest/portals/0/Images/about-person3.jpg']").pinit(); 
        $("[src='/pinterest/portals/0/Images/about-us-group.jpg']").pinit();

    });
    </script>
```

But i am getting this as

```
 <script src="$(function () {$([src='/pinterest/portals/0/Images/about-us-group.jpg']).pinit();});" type="text/javascript">
```

How can i add `$([src='/pinterest/portals/0/Images/about-us-group.jpg']).pinit();});` between  tags .

Comment: Yes. That's because you're assigning your script to the src attribute. scriptTagLinks.Attributes["src"] = scrip; You should use scriptTagLinks.InnerText = scrip;

Comment: change this `"$(function () {$([src='" + url + "']" + ").pinit();});"` 
to `"$(function () {$([src='" + url + "']" + ").pinit(); [src='" + secondurl + "']"});"` where secondurl will be `/pinterest/portals/0/Images/about-us-group.jpg`